# colocar nome do usuario no Card flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, firebase-database

sou novo no flutter e estou com algumas duvidas.

estou tentando colocar o nome do usuário logado no meu app em um Card, em um listView, meu código está dessa forma

initState com a chamada do método que busca os dados no firebase

```
  void initState() {
    _getUid();
    _getUser();
    super.initState();
  }
```

metodo que busca os dados no firebase

```
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await db.collection("Users").get().then(
          (value) => {
            for (var doc in value.docs)
              {
                print("${doc.id} => ${doc.data()["Nome"]}"),
                nomeUsuario = doc.data()["Nome"]
              },
            print("sucesso"),
          },
          onError: (e) => print("erro"),
        );

    print(nomeUsuario);
  }
```

onde tento mostrar o valor na tela

```
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Perfil"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
              child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(nomeUsuario != null ? nomeUsuario! : ""),
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                  trailing: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right))),
```

o retorno na tela do app aparece o seguinte

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando dou um hotReload com o Ctrl+S no código ele aparece normal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Quando o método que obtém suas informações tiver o retorno do Firebase, chame o método [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html).

Esse método avisa que o estado dessa tela mudou e assim o framework vai saber que é para redesenhar ela com as novas informações.

Segue o exemplo no seu caso:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await db.collection("Users").get().then(
          (value) => {
            for (var doc in value.docs)
              {
                print("${doc.id} => ${doc.data()["Nome"]}"),
                nomeUsuario = doc.data()["Nome"]
              },
            print("sucesso"),
            setState((){}); //Chame setState aqui,
          },
          onError: (e) => print("erro"),
        );

    print(nomeUsuario);
    setState((){}); //Ou chame aqui, se sua função estiver marcada como async

  }
```

Esse método recebe como parâmetro uma função, de forma que você pode encapsular a mudança de estado dentro de um callback para ficar mais evidente. Não é obrigatório, mas ajuda a deixar claro o quê no estado você mudou. Um exemplo:

```
//Isso:
setState(() { variavel = novoValor; });
//É a mesma coisa que:
variavel = novoValor;
setState((){});
```

Existem outras formas de você resolver isso. Como seu método retorna um [Future](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html), você poderia usar um [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) que já se atualiza automaticamente caso o estado do Future informado mude.

Para mais informações, consulte a documentação oficial sobre estado, [aqui](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) (em inglês).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, Muito obrigado!!

Comment: @JoãoVictor De nada! Se a resposta lhe agradou, não se esqueça de aceitá-la para ajudar futuras buscas no site. Você pode aceitá-la clicando no (✔️) ao lado da resposta escolhida.